# what's the syntax error for a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

A syntax error was found near to:

```
Create table *** (
'id'...
'sid'...
'api_name'...
...
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`) COMMENT '',
      KEY `idx_sid` (`sid`) COMMENT '',
      KEY `idx_api_name` (`api_name`)
)
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: What is the whole query?

Comment: your question is not clear. can you please post the query?

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: I just wonder if I can append comment'' after the PRIMARY KEY setting?

Comment: ...and it's an empty comment... is it related to the database server config?

Comment: @user1782784 no, `COMMENT` has no problem, maybe the error exists before `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the column names were wrap with single quotes when it should be backtick if it's a reserved keyword.

Wrapping column names with **single quotes converts** the *identifier* into *string literals*.

```
Create table *** 
(
   id...
   sid...
   api_name...
   ...
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) COMMENT '',
      KEY `idx_sid` (`sid`) COMMENT '',
      KEY `idx_api_name` (`api_name`)
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3164)

Comment: what do you need to know more?

Comment: you're right, I should use ` rather than ', but also I find the problem is that comment cannot be added for indexes... right?

Comment: no, comment **CAN** be added on the indexes, see the fiddle above `:D`

Comment: I tried but it failed again... and I checked on several visual editors, they don't provide a column named 'comment' for indexes. They do provide 'comment' for tables. so ?

Comment: see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ae63/1

Answer (score 0):

Field names must not be enclosed with quotes (**'**) but with **back-ticks** (**`**).

Enclosing field names with back-ticks is only necessary if:

- The field name has more than one word (separated with spaces)
- The field name is a reserved keyword